# Whisper who am I

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Guess my friend.

---

> A tail and mouths comprise me,
>   for shy I am
>   my hands fight continuously,
>   But give others jam.

Hint

> Alone I am weak, with a friend I am powerful.
>  I do not create, but propagate.
>  Nowadays, they cut my tail and hands,
>  It does not bother me much as I can speak as much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be

> **earbuds**.

```
A tail and mouths comprise me,
```

> **tail** is the single cord that plugs into a device, like a phone.
>  **mouths** are the two speakers in the earbuds proper.

```
for shy I am
```

> You hide inside people's ears

```
my hands fight continuously,
```

> **hands** are the two cords that lead to the earbuds themselves, linking them with the  "tail".
>  They "fight" because they're always getting tangled with each other.

```
But give others jam.
```

> As in music.

Hint

> `Alone I am weak, with a friend I am powerful.`
>  Earbuds by themselves do nothing. Plug them into something and they can now function.

> `I do not create, but propagate.`
>  Earbuds only play back what others have said or recorded.

> `Nowadays, they cut my tail and hands,`
>     `It does not bother me much as I can speak as much.`
>  Modern bluetooth earbuds have no "tail" or "hands" wiring, but work just as well.

Answer (score 7):

Totally random idea but I think it (mostly) works

> Deadmau5

A tail and mouths comprise me,

> the tail is the cable at the back of his mask and the mouths are his real mouth and the one drawn on his mask

for shy I am

> we rarely see his face in concert

my hands fight continuously,

> has a lot to do with his hands in concert

But give others jam.

> like in a music jam?

Comment: I like this answer ^^ but why not Marshmello then ?

Comment: Simply because before googling it I did not know Marshmello (I'm not especially fond of electronic music so I don't know many artists)

Comment: The question would'he had a trivia or knowledge tag if it was this person.

Answer (score 3):

Probably:

> Hand food mixer

A tail and mouths comprise me,

> The electric wire and the openings for the whisks

for shy I am

> Not sure

my hands fight continuously,

> when it runs

But give others jam.

> it is used for mixing

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are:

> A karaoke microphone

A tail and mouths comprise me,

> The tail of the microphone wire, the mouths of the people that sing.

for shy I am

> Many people feel nervous about singing in the company of other people.

my hands fight continuously,

> The microphone is passed around to people eager to show they are the best.

But give others jam.

> People sing not just for the purpose of competition, but having fun and rocking out to good music.

Alone I’am weak, with a friend I’am powerful.

> A microphone by itself is useless. You need a sound system to convert the electrical signal to an amplified sound.

Comment: A very close answer but not the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure but let's try:

> [Wind Instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_instrument), especially brass wind instrument

A tail and mouths comprise me,

> You can see many wind instruments like having a tail and a big mouth

for shy I am

> Not really sure, is it because it "shy"-ny?

my hands fight continuously,

> Some instruments like trumpet, is played by moving it "hand". Other instruments played by "hold/stop" the wind blowed by pressing the keys or holes, and it look like our finger and the instrument fight continuously

But give other jam,

> it gives music jam

Alone I’am weak, with a friend I’am powerful

> Some instruments is played together (not solo) to make a better sound

Answer (score 1):

You are

> An electric speaker

A tail and mouths comprise me,

for shy I am

> The cord is the tail and the speakers (tweeter, woofer, etc.) are the mouths

my hands fight continuously,

> No idea

But give others jam.

> I assume jam is a reference to music?

Alone I am weak, with a friend I am powerful.

> Without someone to play sound through it, a speaker is silent

I do not create, but propagate.

> A speaker propagates sound

Nowadays, they cut my tail and hands,

It does not bother me much as I can speak as much.

> Many speakers are wireless now

Comment: Very close to the answer, but i want the specific term.

Answer (score -2):

> I just imagine a cat hahah is this a cat?

Comment: Hi Elsa, and welcome to Puzzling!  For a riddle like this, we ask that you explain how each line of the puzzle relates to your answer.